# Remove whole line based value of the last field

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If I find any value from 64512 to 65535 at the last field, then the whole line will be removed:

sample data:

```
20170101|1.0.136.0/24|2497 38040 28969
20170101|1.0.137.0/24|2497 38040 33423
20170101|1.0.138.0/24|2497 38040 64603
20170101|1.0.139.0/24|2497 38040 10136
20170101|1.0.142.0/24|2497 38040 65222
20170101|1.0.144.0/24|2497 38040 65535
```

Expected output:

```
20170101|1.0.136.0/24|2497 38040 28969
20170101|1.0.137.0/24|2497 38040 33423
20170101|1.0.139.0/24|2497 38040 10136
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to do it.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by the "last field".  Is this data delimited by `|`, making the last field in the first line the string `2497 38040 28969`?  Or, is the text delimited by spaces, and the last field is just `28969`? The latter is much easier to do:

```
awk '$NF<64512 || $NF > 65535' input-file
```

If the former, you'll need to work a bit harder.

Comment: It works for me, I meant the text delimited by spaces, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try: If you have same Input_file like sample shown then following too help you in same.

```
while read a b c
do
    if [[ $c > 64512 && $c < 65535 ]]
    then
        echo $a $b $c
    fi
done < "Input_file"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk ' $4 < 64512  && $4 > 65535 ' sample.txt
```

$4 - fourth field that needs to be checked greater than 64512 and less than 65535 ,not to print these lines..

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$3<33424' file

20170101|1.0.136.0/24|2497 38040 28969
20170101|1.0.137.0/24|2497 38040 33423
20170101|1.0.139.0/24|2497 38040 10136
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.